# Transform non-linear HJB PDE into system of linear ODEs

Tags: stochastic-calculus, optimization, market-microstructure, market-making

I am reading this market making [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3115.pdf), and am trying to understand the transformation presented on page 6. A good resource for background relevant to the transformation is this other market-making [paper](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Eavellane/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf). Could anyone point me to a resource on this transformation?

Comment: What is exactly your question? How it is derived, or what is the intuition behind it? If you plug in the exponential intensity from page 4 into the equation, you can calculate the suprema explicitly, so the equation becomes linear. And it's not uncommon for parabolic equations to have factorization as in Proposition 1 (for example, in terms of eigenfunctions).

Comment: Please do not provide links for the majority of the question. Please make the question more fully formed from a stand alone perspective.